# Pine script indicator convert into strategy

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

Can somebody convert this script into strategy. its an indicator, but i want to convert into a strategy.

- Long condition: if price closes above trend line
- Short Condition: if price closes below trend line

[image: Link of ScreenShot]

```
indicator("Heikin Ashi [Improved]", overlay=true)

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Input
REAL = input(false, title="Use Real Close?", group="Heikin Ashi [Improved]", tooltip="Get the real closing price per bar close")
HA = input(true, title="Add Original Heikin Ashi Smoothness?", group="Heikin Ashi [Improved]", tooltip="Add an extra layer of smoothness.")
s = input.int(1, minval=1, maxval=100, title="Candle Smoothness", group="Heikin Ashi [Improved]")

ShowAvg = input(true, title="Show Heikin Ashi Moving Average [improved]", group="Heikin Ashi Moving Average [improved]", tooltip="Display a moving average based on the improved Heikin Ashi bars.")
len = input.int(25, minval=1, maxval=500, title="Length", group="Heikin Ashi Moving Average [improved]", tooltip="Set moving average length.")

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Heikin Ashi [improved]
close0 =  (open + high + low + close) / 4
close0 :=  na(close0)? nz(na) : (nz(close0) + nz(close)) / 2          
open0 = float(na)
open0 :=  na(open0[1])? nz(na) :  (nz(open0[s]) + nz(close0[1])) / 2   
high0 = math.max(high, math.max(open0,close0))  
low0 = math.min(low, math.min(open0,close0))

h = math.max(high0,low0)
l = math.min(high0,low0)
 
 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Original Heikin Ashi Smoothness 
haClose = (open0 + h + l + close0) / 4
haOpen = float(na)
haOpen := na(haOpen[1]) ? (open0 + close0) / 2 : (nz(haOpen[1]) + nz(haClose[1])) / 2
haHigh = math.max(h, math.max(haOpen, haClose))
haLow = math.min(l, math.min(haOpen, haClose)) 
//plotcandle(haOpen,haHigh,haLow,close, color=haClose>haOpen?color.lime:color.red, title="Heikin Ashi [improved] + Original Heikin Ashi Smoothness")

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Candle Mode
o_ = HA? haOpen : open0
h_ = HA? haHigh : h
l_ = HA? haLow : l 
c_ = HA? REAL? close: haClose : REAL? close: close0
 
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Coloring 
BODY = close0>open0?color.lime:color.red
BORDER = close0>open0?color.lime:color.red
if HA 
    BODY := haClose>haOpen?color.lime:color.red
    BORDER := haClose>haOpen?color.lime:color.red
    
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Plot Candle
plotcandle(o_,h_,l_,c_, color=BODY, bordercolor=BORDER, title="Heikin Ashi [improved]")


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// Heikin Ashi Moving Average [improved]
avg = math.avg(high0,low0,haHigh,haLow,c_)
HA_movingAverage = ta.wma(avg, len)
col = HA_movingAverage>HA_movingAverage[1]? color.lime:color.red
plot(ShowAvg?HA_movingAverage:na, color=col, title="Heikin Ashi Moving Average [improved]")
```

Comment: Sorry but we are here to help you not to code everything for you.

Comment: then atleast help me

Comment: Where do you need help? Show us what you have tried and what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Change `indicator` to `strategy` at the top of your script. Boom. Done.

You'll want to use something like `ta.crossover` and `ta.crossunder` for your entry conditions.

Then you'll need to read the docs on how to actually make an `entry` or `order`. That's a separate thing.

Comment: Thank you for your help. these are the things that i already know. i am having difficulties in making long and short condtion. can you help me out. ?

Comment: You asked specifically "if price closes above trend line".  The answer to that is use `ta.crossover` to test when the price (`close`) closes above the `HA_movingAverage` series you have.  You don't already know it, or you'd have done it ;)

Comment: Thank you for your help. i have made with your help. now the only problem is giving me the error of bool and simple float

`//strategy`
`EMA = ta.wma(avg, len)`

`short1 = HA_movingAverage<HA_movingAverage[1]`
`long1 = HA_movingAverage>HA_movingAverage[1]`
`long2 = out2 > EMA`
`short2 = out2 < EMA`

`longtrade = out3 < (long1 and long2)`
`shorttrade = out3 > (short1 and short2)`

Comment: This issue has been resolved. can you please tell me how to setup a trade with condition like Long only above EMA(out3) and short only below Ema(out3)?

Comment: @MahmudAyaz You'll need to ask a separate question now.  SO tries to keep each question specific so it's easier to search for others.